# Adding an additional layer to existing hosted feature layer on ArcGIS Online

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, online

I have already created a hosted feature layer that contains four separate layers.
To upload these, I created a compressed file of the shapefiles for the four layers, and uploaded that as my hosted feature layer.

I would like to add an additional layer to this hosted feature layer, but I can't figure out how. I know how to open the layer in the Map Viewer and add a layer that way, but that is only temporary.

I would like to add it permanently, without having to re-create everything else.

Comment: Hello @Melissa, do you have a desktop application (ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro)?

Comment: Hi @YogeshChavan, I have ArcMap 10.7